# Generate a document form google form and keep it sync upon each submission

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-spreadsheets

I have a Use case in which, I have a google form with several fields and a dropdown which has 3 options. Each option in the drop down menu should be linked to a spreadsheet/pdf(in our case 3 separate spreadsheets/pdf). Now when ever a user submits the form, all the fields from the form have to be added to the file which is mapped to the dropdown.

Let's say I have a google form with a single field "Name" and a dropdown "Class" having 2 options "Class 1" and "Class 2" and Class 1 is mapped to Class1.xsl and Class 2 is mapped to Class2.xsl. Now a user fills the name in the form and selects "Class 1" from the dropdown and submits the form. During submission, the data in the "Name" field is taken and added to the Class1.xsl since the user chose "Class 1" from the dropdown.

Is there any extension available in google form to do perform this use case??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things,

1. Use the `=IMPORTRANGE()` function to move the data from the form sheet, to the other sheet
2. On the drop down classes use [Data Validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on a "List From A Range" and have that range update with data from the form

Hope that works, but without any data I can't give a better answer

Comment: I'll check that solution @Chef1075

Comment: @BalajeeKs if it works for you make sure to vote up and close the answer